# How to add one column of an intermediate table to the final result table

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm a SQL newbie here. I've encountered the task to output a table that contains two columns: Service name and a count(the number of time this service is requested).

Now I have a n intermediate table which contains two columns as well. Instead of the service name column, it has a service ID column which can be used to retrieve service names from a Service table.

I'm wondering how to keep the count column so that I can add it in the final result, after translating the IDs to their names. I tried to use With (...) As to store the intermediate table, but Oracle does not seem to recognize the syntax. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Check out docs page for INNER JOIN, several examples: https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rrefsqlj35034.html

Comment: Why do you need an intermediate table - why not just join whichever table you're getting the counts from to the service table before counting?

Answer (score 0):

This query will allow you to make a third table based on the first two tables.

```
CREATE TABLE table3
AS
SELECT * FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.ServiceId = table2.ServiceId
```

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you posted what you really have (tables' description) and some sample data along with desired output.

This is how I understood it:

Sample data:

```
SQL> with
  2  service (service_id, name) as
  3    (select 1, 'Service 1' from dual union all
  4     select 2, 'Service 2' from dual
  5    ),
  6  intermediate (inter_id, service_id, datum) as
  7    (select 1, 1, date '2022-05-13' from dual union all
  8     select 2, 1, date '2022-04-28' from dual union all
  9     select 3, 1, date '2022-03-07' from dual
 10    )
```

Query begins here; it selects service name and number of times each service was requested. Tables are outer joined (because service #2 doesn't have any requests yet so you wouldn't get it at all if it were inner join):

```
 11  select s.name,
 12         count(i.inter_id) times_requested
 13  from service s left join intermediate i on i.service_id = s.service_id
 14  group by s.name
 15  order by s.name;

NAME      TIMES_REQUESTED
--------- ---------------
Service 1               3
Service 2               0

SQL>
```